# C - Ternary operator

Tags: c

Why when I'm doing this:

```
int     ft_is_alpha(char *str, int i)
{
    return (((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

It crashing but, when I'm doing this:

```
int     ft_is_alpha(char *str, int i)
{
    if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
        return (1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

It doesn't crashing.. 
I call the function like this

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (ft_is_equal_to(str, i))
        {
            ++count;
            int     j;

            j = i - 1;
            while (str[++j] != '\0' && ft_is_alpha(str, j))
            {
                ++length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it is crashing, probably it is invoking an undefined behavior. Either your `i` is out of `str` bounds, or the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What is `i`? or how are you calling this function?

Comment: Is it the caller that is crashing? Since your two versions return opposite results.

Comment: You *do* realize that a comparison already returns a boolean?

Comment: Is there a sequence point in this? `while (str[++j] != '\0' && ft_is_alpha(str, j))` since `j` can start at `-1` and is the evaluation sequence guaranteed to be left to right?

Comment: @Weather Vane: Yes there is, so the code is well defined, but the style hurts the reader's eyes.

Comment: Why not pass `str[i]` instead of `str` and `i` separately?  What does the function  `ft_is_equal_to()` do?

Comment: ...or even use `isalpha(str[i])`

Comment: @Weather Vane: good try, but it should really be `isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])`, and would not be exactly equivalent if the locale is not `C`.

Comment: @chqrlie it is `int isalpha(int)` so `char` will be promoted by the compiler. But I take your point: `isalpha` is UB if the argument is not `00..FF`

Comment: @Weather Vane: yes, that's exactly why you should cast the `char` argument!  depending on your compiler's settings, `char` may be `signed` by default and promotion will produce negative values.  C11 7.4 is clear about this for `int isalpha(int c)`, like all similar functions from `<ctype.h>`: *In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *crashing*, the first function implements the test correctly but returns the opposite of the correct value. The branches of the ternary operator should be in the same order as in the `if (cond) {} else {}` statement.  It should read:

```
int ft_is_alpha(char *str, int i) {
    return (((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Since the condition already evaluates to a boolean, you can simplify the code by removing the unneeded ternary operator and some parentheses:

```
int ft_is_alpha(const char *str, int i) {
    return (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z');
}
```

Removing the last sets of parentheses can be done, but with less readability.

Note that `str` should be declared `const char *` as the string is not modified by the function.  Also remove the parentheses in `return (1);`, they are not needed and considered bad style.

Furthermore, why not pass `str[i]` instead of `str` and `i` separately? This change of API would make the code much easier to read, faster to execute and safer to use.